# Owl carousel not displaying next previous button in simple html design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

[image]I am using Owl carousel in my html desing. It is working fine but not displaying next and previous button. Then I have added button in my page still it is not displaying. And I have also implemented in same way in my Laravel blade template in it's working fine with next previous button. I have added Owl carousel version 2.3.4.
Here is my code which I have done in my Html:

I have added pictures of it. in first picture it is working fine with laravel blade. And in second it is not displaying arrow button for next and previous. [image]
I have searched it but I didn't got any proper solution. Does anyone knows what is wrong with it? Did I missed something? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boxicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="features">
     <img src="images/features  -bg.jpg" alt="Fitzoh" class="features-bg">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-left">
              <h6 class="text-light-green">Standout with Fitzoh</h6>
              <div class="divider-sm"></div>
              <h2>Take your fitness business to the next level</h2>
              <p>With Fitzoh, adopting a better client experience has been made easier than ever.</p>
              <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-round">Know More</a>
              <div class="features-list mt48 text-left">
                 <a href="#one" class="feature mb24 active">
                    <p class="mb0">Add value to your brand through your own application</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#two" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Enhance client experience through virtual training</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#three" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Create your own excercise and diet plans</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#four" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Easy Scheduling & performance tracking</p>
                 </a>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-right">
              <div class="owl-carousel">
                 <div class="item" data-hash="one">
                    <img class="block-image" src="images/feature1.png" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="two">
                    <img class="block-image" src="images/feature2.png" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="three">
                    <img class="block-image" src="images/feature3.png" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="four">
                    <img class="block-image" src="images/feature1.png" alt="image">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="owl-nav">
              <!-- thess buttons I have added manually -->
              <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev">
              <span aria-label="Previous">‹</span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next">
              <span aria-label="Next">›</span>
              </button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/common.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to ask about owl carousel and you don't have show any initialization of that, please add code of that too.

Comment: Owl carousel config use `nav: true,` to show navigation

Comment: I have added it. It's not working! @AJAY MAURYA

Comment: I have already added the whole code of carousel!  @Just code

Comment: @KinjalVithalani where do you initialize it?

Comment: @KinjalVithalani make sure that other scripts are not causing any conflicts, change scripts orders. Check the jQuery version also.

Comment: Okay I will check it!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
  navText: ['<span aria-label="Previous">‹</span>','<span aria-label="Next">›</span>'],
  lazyLoad:true,
    });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button{width:25px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #ccc !important;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="features">
     <!-- <img src="images/features  -bg.jpg" alt="Fitzoh" class="features-bg"> -->
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-left">
              <h6 class="text-light-green">Standout with Fitzoh</h6>
              <div class="divider-sm"></div>
              <h2>Take your fitness business to the next level</h2>
              <p>With Fitzoh, adopting a better client experience has been made easier than ever.</p>
              <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-round">Know More</a>
              <div class="features-list mt48 text-left">
                 <a href="#one" class="feature mb24 active">
                    <p class="mb0">Add value to your brand through your own application</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#two" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Enhance client experience through virtual training</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#three" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Create your own excercise and diet plans</p>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#four" class="feature mb24">
                    <p class="mb0">Easy Scheduling & performance tracking</p>
                 </a>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-right">
              <div class="owl-carousel">
                 <div class="item" data-hash="one">
                    <img class="block-image" src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/20151028/pngtree-Design-Light-Texture-Wallpaper-background-photo-674871.jpg" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="two">
                    <img class="block-image" src="https://blog.sonicwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SNWL-image-412.jpg" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="three">
                    <img class="block-image" src="http://www.rishtiindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background-Image-of-Flyer-Brochure.jpg" alt="image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item" data-hash="four">
                    <img class="block-image" src="https://ane4bf-datap1.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wmocms/s3fs-public/news/featured_media/featured-image-index.png?4t5V5QpQ.h.L2MpEUHsgfJM_lASy4dbb" alt="image">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's not working!! @AJAY MAURYA

Comment: I have run it and also added same code in my code but it is not working! infect images are also not showing after adding this code! I guess it happens because something is replacing carouser's css or js. Don't know what!!?

Comment: witch version owl-carousel library you use?

Comment: I am using version 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    dots:false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**nav:true -> Enable arrow navigation,
dots:true -> Enable dot navigation**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            dots: true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:true,
            dots: true
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            dots: true
        }
    }
})
```